# Making an input form popup inside a textarea using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, forms

I've created a textarea form (instead of creating a ul list) where it will display all the users' messages, I've also created an input form where the user types in their message. I'd like to make the input form appear on the textarea when the user's cursor hovers on the textarea as shown in the image here

```
<form id="message-form" action="#" method="post">
  <input id="message" placeholder="Write your message here...>
            <button type="submit">Send Message</button>
  <button type="button" id="close">Close Connection</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need jQuery for something like this; just use CSS:

```
input.focus-actions:focus + .submit {
  display: block;
}
.submit {
  display: none;
}
```

Where your html might look something like this:

```
<form action = "/">
    <fieldset>
        <legend>My Focus Form</legend>
        <input type = "text" class = "focus-actions" placeholder = "Write your message here..." required autofocus/>
        <footer class = "submit">
            <button type = submit>Send Message</button>
            <button>Close</button>
        </footer>
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

Also, if you want it to fade in, you can use animations:

```
.submit {
  -webkit-animation: fadeIn 1s ease;
  -o-animation: fadeIn 1s ease;
  animation: fadeIn 1s ease;
}
@-moz-keyframes fadeIn {
  0% {
    -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=0)";
    filter: alpha(opacity=0);
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    -ms-filter: none;
    filter: none;
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
@-webkit-keyframes fadeIn {
  0% {
    -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=0)";
    filter: alpha(opacity=0);
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    -ms-filter: none;
    filter: none;
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
@-o-keyframes fadeIn {
  0% {
    -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=0)";
    filter: alpha(opacity=0);
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    -ms-filter: none;
    filter: none;
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
@keyframes fadeIn {
  0% {
    -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=0)";
    filter: alpha(opacity=0);
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    -ms-filter: none;
    filter: none;
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
```